# UpsertItem with a condition check in azure-cosmos sdk 4

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

java cosmosclient getting used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have a container in cosmos SQL which have lastChangeTimestamp.
Now i have to upsert same item (with new values) but only when it is the latest item based on the timestamp present in DB and new item need to be uploaded.
Currently i am doing it by fetching  the  lastChangeTimestamp and comparing in application and then taking decision to upsert , This makes it 2 calls , Can it be make 1 single call upserting if condition is true at db side?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your want to do something like:

```
update xxx set xxx where timestamp = max(timestamp)
```

This is not supported now.You can trace this feature at [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6346033-set-based-operations-insert-update-delete).

Comment: Thanks ,  above expression has 2 things partial update and conditional check while updating , Currently i am looking for updating whole document but with a condition  timestamp_in_document  < :INPUT_TIMESTAMP_IN_QUERY. So i am not looking for parital updates is that possible